# Communication in Electron and React components

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I would have liked to know if it was possible to retrieve information from a computer with the "[systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation)" module or even open a program directly in a react application by clicking on a button from a component combined with electron. I managed to integrate my react application with electron but I have no idea how communication between the two libraries works.

Comment: Need to expose a simple server from the electron side, we can get the data through rest API or WebSockets from the server.

Comment: @GokulaKannanT do you have concrete examples because i don't think this is possible in the case where i wish to launch an .exe on the client pc by clicking on a button with react